# Integromat custom webhook queue keeps filling with the same salesforce data

Tags: salesforce, webhooks, make.com

I have an Integromat scenario setup that starts with a custom webhook.  The data to the webhook comes from Salesforce.  Everything is working fine except the webhook queue seems to keep running the same data every 2 hours.  For example, I do the thing in Salesforce that triggers the outbound message to the webhook, Integromat scenario triggers and does what I want.....Then two hours later it does it again....then two more hours it does it again.  As if the server buffer is not clearing (wild guess, and I don't think Integromat would even allow access to clear this).

I had a very similar flow on Zapier, triggered by the **exact** same Salesforce event so I don't think it's Salesforce sending the data on a loop.  I am trying to migrate the workflow from Zapier to Integromat for cost reasons but obviously can't do it if this bug isn't fixed.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: In Salesforce setup, under Environments > Monitoring > Outbound Messages, check if there are any failures. If Salesforce is sending the message multiple times, it's because of a failure and you'll see it there. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_notifications.htm

Comment: Is your application sending the SOAP acknowledgement back? And is SOAP the only thing it can support, all the cool kids use Platform Events/Streaming API/Change Data Capture now...https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/platform_events_basics

Comment: @Diego and eyescream thanks for the help.  was able to solve with that info.  posted the solution.  Guess I'm one of the cool kids now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Diego and eyescream.  I was able to see in Salesforce that the message was failing on the Salesforce side because an acknowledgment was not sent back.  For anyone else who has this issue in Integromat, you need to add a second step Webhook Response and structure it like:

Status: 200

Body:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <notificationsResponse xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound">
        <Ack>true</Ack>
    </notificationsResponse>
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then it worked and SF got the acknowledgment and stoped trying to send the message.  I didn't need to add any custom headers.

Comment: Makes sense. Zapier does this automatically when using the "New Outbound Message" trigger.